# i am getting XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

i am getting  XMLHttpRequest cannot load.so how to remove this error ,please any suggetion for that.

```
                    function soapRCA(){
             var productServiceUrl =           "https://www.ilportaledellautomobilista.it/eai/AreaVeicolo- ws/services/secure/coperturaRC";
       var tipoDiVettura = $('#tipoVeicolo').val();
            var targaperRCA = $('#targaRCA').val();

               var SoaMessage = '<soapenv:Envelope                          xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'+ 
           '<soapenv:Header>'+
        '<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">'+
            '<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="XWSSGID-1253605895203984534550" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">'+
                '<wsse:Username>paolo.pelliccione</wsse:Username>'+
                '<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">tdlemon900mj</wsse:Password>'+ 
            '</wsse:UsernameToken>'+
        '</wsse:Security>'+
    '</soapenv:Header>'+
    '<soapenv:Body>'+ 
        '<CoperturaRCVeicoloSecureRequest xmlns="http://www.dtt.it/xsd/Veicolo">'+ 
            '<tipoVeicolo>'+tipoDiVettura+'</tipoVeicolo>'+
            '<targa>'+targaperRCA+'</targa>'+
        '</CoperturaRCVeicoloSecureRequest>'+
    '</soapenv:Body>'+ 
'</soapenv:Envelope>';

      $.ajax({
     url: productServiceUrl,
      type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
        data: SoaMessage,
     complete: showResult2,
           contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
     crossDomain: true,
      cache: false
     });

       return false;
        }

        function showResult2(xmlHttpRequest, status) {
        //alert('edew00');
        var data =  $(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML).find('#listMovimenti tbody');


     console.log(data);



      //alert('ecco data: '+JSON.stringify(data));

        /*var data = (''+response).substring((''+response).indexOf('<form                id="ListaCoperturaRCVeicolo"'),(''+response).length);
          data = data.substring(0,data.indexOf('</form>'));
         $('#targapage #fintoiframe').html(data);

          var ris = $('#targapage       #fintoiframe').find('#ListaCoperturaRCVeicolo').html();
       $('#targapage #risultatorcaEsterna').html(ris);  */          


       }



       </script>
```

Comment: Same origin policy ?

Comment: what?
tell me @adeneo

Comment: For one thing, GET is not appropriate for this request. Use POST.

Comment: There's a space in your webservice URL, and indeed "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" (same origin policy) is the error.

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load" — What is the **exact** and **complete** error message you get?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.ilportaledellautomobilista.it/eai/AreaVeicolo-ws/services/secur…n.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">tdlemon900mj</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><CoperturaRCVeicoloSecureRequest xmlns="http://ditpl.com/paolo/paolo/"><tipoVeicolo>A</tipoVeicolo><targa>BJ330VW</targa></CoperturaRCVeicoloSecureRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://dtt.com' is therefore not allowed access.